How do I reduce the file size of screen recordings?
I am using the default screen recording tool. The recordings it is producing are at roughly 100mb/min. That is insane for just a short and simple recording.
I looked online, and no one else seems to be having this issue. I could not find any options related to the screenshot tool besides keybindings in either the regular settings or dfconf. I tried reducing my screen resolution and cropping it to only the relevant part of the screen, and it was still roughly the same sized video.
I am not trying to record anything fancy here and so don't really want to install another program to do this when there is one built in by default. I saw one guy complaining about how you needed to install another codec to get it to record in MP4, but I actually do need this recording as a WebM.

No it doesn't.  I tried using installing it and then restarting my computer because I thought it might install some codecs or something that would help but it doesnt reduce the file size at all.  VLC is a video playback tool, besides the chance that some of it's requirements could do this, why would you even think it would help?

VLC application is not only a video player but also a tool to compress videos without compromising their quality.
Set codec, bitrate, frame rate and quality to reduce file size.
Select a video codec that suits your needs, adjust the bitrate to reduce file size and regulate the frame rate.
Run VLC, navigate to Media ---> Convert/Save, click +Add to load your video.
Then click Convert/Save.
Select a format from the Profile drop-down list
Click the Edit Selected Profile icon.
On the Video Codec tab, choose Encoding Parameters. Adjust the codec, bitrate, quality, frame rate and click Save.
Click Browse to select the output folder and rename the file.
Finally, click Start to begin the conversion process

An effective way to compress video is to transcode it to a more efficient format.
To do this you should choose a compression-friendly format such as "H.265 + MP3 (MP4)" from the "Profile" drop-down menu.
Alternatively, you can crop out unnecessary portions.
In VLC, navigate to "Tools" and select "Effects & Filters."
In the "Adjustments & Effects" window, go to the "Video Effects" tab and check the "Crop" box.
Customize the crop values ​​to remove unwanted areas of the video.
Click "Close" to apply the changes.


I ended up using ffmpeg as it is more fully featured for video compression than VLC.  I still think there should be a way to reduce the resolution and frame-rate of the initial recording though
